# Recommendation of budget Windows VPS

Tags: windows, vps, hosting

Does anybody has any recommendation of the above mention subject? Share with me your windows VPS if you have.

Comment: What does "VPS" mean?

Comment: Virtual Private Server. Usually a virtual machine hosted by someone. It's an alternative to a dedicated server in colocation rack.

Comment: What do you want to run on that VPS? Is 256mb ram enough for you, or do you want 1gb, etc?

Comment: ASP.net application, windows services. Probably 512mb should be enough

Comment: Product and service recommendations are specifically off topic for ServerFault (see point 4 in the NOT About section of the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq))

Answer (score 1):

webhostingtalk.com can help if you have other requirements besides cost.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/12655/cheap-vps)

Comment: I mean Windows, not linux

Answer (score 0):

From the question that Sam linked you to, [www.vpsland.com](http://www.vpsland.com) seems to be the cheapest Windows VPS host.

Comment: Support is generally very slow to reply and unavailable nights and weekends.

Answer (score 0):

We are using [ElasticHosts](http://www.elastichosts.com) as lower-cost alternative to Amazon EC2.  For us the main advantage is that we can install Windows ourselves and thus use our existing licenses.  To test it out I'd recommend installing the Server 2008 Trial on it.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a lot of searching on this one. The cheapest I could find are:

- Softsyshosting http://www.softsyshosting.com/Windows-VPS-HyperV.aspx
- Godaddy http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/virtual-dedicated-servers.aspx

I have used SoftSys and it's nice. Support calls get answers in less than half an hour and general load / speed is pretty acceptable.

Not sure about Godaddy, it's slightly cheaper but if I remember correctly, their shared hosting has a lot of comments about loaded servers and support issues. Not sure about VPS.

Note that Windows is a beast in terms of resources compared to Linux or even previous versions of Windows! Windows can easily take 10+ GB HDD space for itself, and 0.5-1.0 GB of RAM, so, in practice I wouldn't recommend any VPS plan with less than 2 GB RAM. I'd think any VPS with less than 1 GB too is quite a joke.